# What is ::* in C++?

Tags: c++

I was reading a basic C++ tutorial when I faced

```
::*
```

in the following code. May I know what that is:

```
class A {
public:
protected:
  int i;
};


class B : public A {
  friend void f(A*, B*);
  void g(A*);
};

void f(A* pa, B* pb) {
//  pa->i = 1;
  pb->i = 2;

//  int A::* point_i = &A::i;
  int A::* point_i2 = &B::i;
}

void B::g(A* pa) {
//  pa->i = 1;
  i = 2;

//  int A::* point_i = &A::i;
  int A::* point_i2 = &B::i;
}

void h(A* pa, B* pb) {
//  pa->i = 1;
//  pb->i = 2;
}

int main() { }
```

Based on my C++ knowledge so far, what is something like the following?

```
int A::* point_i2
```

Comment: A "basic" C++ tutorial? No "basic" C++ anything should be covering member pointers. Do you have a link to that tutorial?

Comment: @NicolBolas may be not very basic :)    http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/lnxpcomp/v8v101/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.xlcpp8l.doc%2Flanguage%2Fref%2Fcplr129.htm

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/pointer#Pointers_to_members

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`point_i2` is a pointer to a member. It means that it points to an `int` member variable that is declared in the class `A`.

Answer (score 6):

```
int A::* point_i2 = &B::i;
```

After this when you have a random `A` or `B` object, you can access the member that `point_i2` points to

```
B b;
b.*point_i2 = ...;
```

After the above initialization of `point_i2`, this would change `b.i`.

Think of `ClassName::*` the same way as you think of `&` and `*`: It's just another "pointer/reference-like tool" you can use in declarations to specify what the thing you declare is going to be.

Comment: So is this like a "member class pointer"? Just like the method class pointers?

Comment: In simpler words. *Pointer to a class Member*.

Comment: @Gui what's a method class pointer? Do you mean `FunctionType A::*` ? Yes, they are the same. A pointer to data member has the member type be an object type, while a pointer to member function has the member type be a function type. Syntactically you can also use the function declarator syntax for the function type to make it look like `R (A::*)(parameters) cv-qual ref-qual except-spec`. Although if you are not familiar with C++ syntax it is easier to use alias templates and write `alias<R(parameters) cv-qual ref-qual except-spec> A::*`.

Comment: @Johannes: This (didnt find a clearer explanation on SO): http://mdzahidh.wordpress.com/2008/07/16/pointer-to-c-class-methods-or-should-you-call-em-method-pointers/