# Interpreting static_cast "static_cast<void (Pet::*)(int)>" syntax?

Tags: c++, pybind11, static-cast

I'm trying to understand the static cast as used in the [Pybind11 docs here](https://pybind11.readthedocs.io/en/stable/classes.html#overloaded-methods). Specifically, they use the syntax

```
static_cast<void (Pet::*)(int)>(&Pet::set)
```

Since I haven't seen this syntax before I'm strugling to interpret and apply to my own code so I was hoping somebody could explain what's going on here. Thanks

## Edit - some context

I am creating Pybind11 bindings to an overloaded method that has two signatures, which only differ by `const` qualification. The class I am binding is a template so I am using [this strategy to create the bindings](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47749076/3059024)

```
    template<class T>
    class Matrix {
    public:

        ...

        /**
         * get the row names
         */
        std::vector<std::string> &getRowNames() {
            return rowNames;
        }

        /**
         * get the row names (mutable)
         */
        const std::vector<std::string> &getRowNames() {
            return rowNames;
        }

    ...
```

My version of the helper function described in that post is this:

```
template<typename T>
void declare_matrix(py::module &m, const std::string &typestr) {
    using Class = ls::Matrix<T>;
    const std::string &pyclass_name = typestr;
    py::class_<Class>(m, pyclass_name.c_str(), py::buffer_protocol(), py::dynamic_attr())
            .def(py::init<unsigned int, unsigned int>())
            .def("getRowNames", static_cast<const std::vector<std::string>(ls::Matrix<T>::*)()>(&ls::Matrix<T>::getRowNames))
```

but the `getRowNames` line produces the following error:

```
Address of overloaded function 'getRowNames' cannot be static_cast to type 'const std::vector<std::string> (ls::Matrix<complex<double>>::*)()'
```

For anybody else reading this, the cast I was able to figure out thanks to the answer is:

```
static_cast< std::vector<std::string>& (ls::Matrix<T>::*)()>(&Class::getRowNames)
```

Comment: `set` is a method of the `Pet` class, and the cast is converting (for some reason) a pointer to that to a pointer to a method of the `Pet` class which takes one `int` parameter and has a `void` return.

Comment: Looking at the documentation it says `We can disambiguate by casting them to function pointers.`. If you don't need to do that disambiguation in your code then you don't need to use this technique.

Comment: I do need the disambiguation unfortunately, my two overloaded functions only differ by `const` (see edits)

Comment: Are you having some specific problem (if so what) or are you just trying to understand? I must admit I've not seen this particular technique before.

Comment: You are missing a `&` in your cast. Try this `static_cast<const std::vector<std::string>&(ls::Matrix<T>::*)()>`

Comment: @john Both actually, I've updated the question with my specific problem but it'd also be nice to understand it

Comment: Well I've pointed out the problem (I hope). The technique relies on the fact that the cast selects only the method that matches the type of the cast and discards the others. Just using the name alone would be ambiguous.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The meaning of:

```
static_cast<void (Pet::*)(int)>(&Pet::set)
```

- `static_cast<T_1>(T_2)` means we're casting type 2 to type 1.
- `T_1`:

  - `(Pet::*)` is a **pointer to a class member of Pet** (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/9939367/14344821 for a further discussion)
  - `void (Pet::*)(int)` is a pointer to a member function that takes an `int` parameter, returning a `void`
- `T_2`

  - `&Pet::set` is the memory location of `Pet::set`

So basically, we're stating explicitly that we are **setting the integer value**.

Now we can bind the `set` function**s** to python (allowing us to set both age and name):

```
   .def("set", static_cast<void (Pet::*)(int)>(&Pet::set), "Set the pet's age")
   .def("set", static_cast<void (Pet::*)(const std::string &)>(&Pet::set), "Set the pet's name");
```

Comment: You're right, thanks for noticing. Edited my comment